# how to spyon modalInstance.close() using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

This is my js file code

```
  $scope.close = function () {
            modalInstance.close();
      };





unit test case for the js code

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope) {
var modalInstance = { close: function() {}, dismiss: function() {} };


$controller('BusinessRuleEditCtrl',
       {
           $scope: scope,
           dataFactory: mockdataFactory,
           $modal: modal,
           modalInstance:modalInstance
       });


  }));
        it(' scope.close () functionality is checked ', function () {
            scope.close();
            spyOn(modalInstance, 'close').toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

when i try to run this spec iam getting error "Cannot read property 'close' of undefined".any suggesion will be appreciated....thanks in advance.